# Rails Routing Error Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm a new rails developer who's creating an application that creates the following issue:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes", :username=>#<Recipe id: 42, name: "Curried Chicken Sandwich", yield: "4 Servings", description: "Burgers aren't the only grilled things we want to e...", created_at: "2013-06-27 18:49:42", updated_at: "2013-06-27 18:49:42", duration: "", author: nil, url: nil, user: 3, image: "curried-chicken-sandwich-646.jpg", user_recipe_id: nil>}
```

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
match "/:username" => "recipes#index"
scope ':username' do
  resources :recipes
end
```

My controller index looks like:

```
def index
 if params[:tag]
  @recipes = Recipe.tagged_with(params[:tag]).where(:user => current_user.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 45)
 else
  @user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
  @search = Recipe.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:search]
    query.with(:user, @user.id)
    query.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 20)
 end
  @recipes = @search.results
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @recipes }
  end
 end
end
```

and my controller show looks like this:

```
def show
   @user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
   @recipe = Recipe.where(:user_recipe_id => params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
   end
end
```

My index view:

```
<% if not @recipes.any? %>
No Recipes
<% else%>

<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>

    <h3><%= link_to recipe.name, recipe %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Why does this happen? The show action is there, but in the error it says it doesn't.

thanks for all help

Comment: Error is probably thrown by view code. Could you show it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use routing scopes that way.

Comment: where is this error triggered?

Comment: @MarekLipka, Ok I just updated my question

Comment: @Lichtamberg, The error shows up on my index page

Comment: Also, If I go to for example localhost:3000/john (where john is username, and John has no recipes associated with him, then the error doesn't show up. Only when john has recipes associated with him does the error show up

Comment: Probably unrelated, but in your show method, are you sure you mean: @recipe = Recipe.where(:user_recipe_id => params[:id]) and not Recipe.find params[:id]?  Your user_recipe_id in your error is nil...

Comment: @GoGoCarl, I had it like that before, but I changed it so I could I have url's like localhost:3000/john/recipes/4 where it would show the 4th recipe associated with the user, not the 4th recipe in the entire table. The user_recipe_id is the counter I use for each user. I'm not sure why its nil though. That's a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to recipe.name, recipe_path(username: @user.username, id: recipe.id) %>
```

Comment: Fix your spelling, and you may also need to pass the actual username and not the user object.  But that's basically what you want.

Comment: @Lichtamberg, Thanks for the response, but the error still shows up?

Comment: @the_ did you try what @GoGoCarl mentioned? Replace `@user` with `@user.username` and make sure to spell `recipe` properly. Does it still not work?

Comment: @theIv I just tried GoGoCarl's suggestion, but it still comes up with the same error. If the user has no recipes associated with him/her though, then no error comes up

Comment: I went ahead and proposed an edit to the answer just to clarify the comments.

Comment: ^^^ Was just about to propose that!

Comment: @Lichtamberg and GoGoCarl, Thanks for all your help, it works great now